# Photoshop Automation of alignment of text layer with image

Tags: photoshop

I have never scripted in photoshop before, so I am wondering if this is possible. The following is currently done manually for over than 300 files. The next time round is for 600 files, therefore I am looking into automating it.

Steps:

1. Make Image Size to 54pixels Hight and 500px Width -- Found that this is doable.
2. Align Image Left.
3. Create a text layer and insert text -- Found that this is doable.
4. Align Text layer 1px to the right of the image.
5. Trim empty space.

Would appreciate any help and pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This script will get you started: Note that in your request you didn't mention what what the original image was going to be and shrinking it to 500 x 54 is going to stretch it one way or another. Step 2, Align the image left, was omitted as you didn't mention what you are aligning this image to. I suspect you are dealing with a large image and what to shrink it down (as long as it's not smaller than 500 x 54) and work from there. I've also omitted stage 4 as I've hard coded the position of the text to be 1 px from the right hand edge (and it vertically centered with Arial font size 18)

Anhyoo.. you should be able to alter the script to your needs.

```
// set the source document
srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

//set preference units
var originalRulerPref = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
var originalTypePref = app.preferences.typeUnits;
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.POINTS;
app.preferences.typeUnits = TypeUnits.POINTS;

// resize image (ignoring the original aspect ratio)
var w = 500;
var h = 54;
var resizeRes = 72;
var resizeMethod = ResampleMethod.BICUBIC;
srcDoc.resizeImage(w, h, resizeRes, resizeMethod)

//create the text
var textStr = "Some text";
createText("Arial-BoldMT", 18.0, 0,0,0, textStr, w-1, 34)
srcDoc.activeLayer.textItem.justification = Justification.RIGHT

//set preference units back to normal
app.preferences.rulerUnits = originalRulerPref;
app.preferences.typeUnits = originalTypePref;

//trim image to transparent width
app.activeDocument.trim(TrimType.TRANSPARENT, true, true, true, true);

// function CREATE TEXT(typeface, size, R, G, B, text content, text X pos, text Y pos)
// --------------------------------------------------------
function createText(fface, size, colR, colG, colB, content, tX, tY)
{

  // Add a new layer in the new document
  var artLayerRef = srcDoc.artLayers.add()

  // Specify that the layer is a text layer
  artLayerRef.kind = LayerKind.TEXT

  //This section defines the color of the hello world text
  textColor = new SolidColor();
  textColor.rgb.red = colR;
  textColor.rgb.green = colG;
  textColor.rgb.blue = colB;

  //Get a reference to the text item so that we can add the text and format it a bit
  textItemRef = artLayerRef.textItem
  textItemRef.font = fface;
  textItemRef.contents = content;
  textItemRef.color = textColor;
  textItemRef.size = size
  textItemRef.position = new Array(tX, tY) //pixels from the left, pixels from the top
}
```

Comment: Mate, Thanks so much. It will definitely be a great start and I should be able to take it from here.I will try to sort the rest out.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you listed is doable in a script.  I suggest you start by reading 'Adobe Intro To Scripting' in your ExtendScript Toolkit program files directory (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Utilities - CS6\ExtendScript Toolkit CS6\SDK\English)